# Se ha producido el error '-2147417848 (80010108)' en tiempo de ejecución: Error en el método 'Value' de objeto 'Range'

Tags: excel, vba

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de facturación en el VBA de Excel, uso sólo un formulario, la idea es que en un label voy mostrando dinamicamente el nombre de un producto y al lado un textbox para que ingrese la cantidad de ese producto, al darle clic en agregar debe guardar ese dato en una tabla y mostrar el siguiente producto, pero después de guardar el primer producto, al intentar guardar el segundo me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando doy en depurar me muestra siempre esta línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
Private Sub Agregar_Cantidad()
    Dim hoja As Worksheet
    Dim tabla As ListObject
    Dim valor() As String
    Dim id_ultimo_registro As Long
    Dim nombre() As String
    Set hoja = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Facturas")
    Set tabla = hoja.ListObjects("TablaFacturaProducto")
    valor = Split(Me.TxtDato.Value, " ")
    id_ultimo_registro = hoja.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If hoja.Range("A" & id_ultimo_registro) <> "" Then
        id_ultimo_registro = id_ultimo_registro + 1
    End If
    hoja.Range("A" & id_ultimo_registro).Value = id_ultimo_registro - 4
    nombre = Split(Me.LabelNombreProductos.Caption, ":")
    hoja.Range("B" & id_ultimo_registro).Value = nombre(0)
    hoja.Range("C" & id_ultimo_registro).Value = CDec(valor(0))
    hoja.Range("D" & id_ultimo_registro).Value = valor(1)
End Sub
```

No tengo idea de qué esté mal, e incluso en la tabla inserta ese id y después da error, así que no tengo idea de porqué después de ingresar el id es que da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Dejo el link del archivo

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rgP-YkxkVhjsGvyLaGgVe0zalsWPCqO7/view?usp=sharing

Al iniciar la macro le mostrará un inputbox donde debe ingresar el nombre del libro (la intención final de este proyecto es poder exportar un libro de excel con todos los datos pero aún no lo termino por ese problema), luego de escribir el nombre del libro lo mandará a la pantalla principal donde deberá darle clic en nueva hoja, allí ubicará el nombre de la hoja y al darle clic se habilitará el textbox donde podrá ingresar los valores, los valores tienen un formato definido que es primero el valor, si es decimal debe de ir con coma, luego de ingresar el valor da un espacio y luego la unidad de medida (k, lb, g, und, bot) etc, son las unidades que aparecen en la hoja de ajustes, en el código.

El error ocurre cuando va a ingresar el segundo producto

Comment: Hola, el código **nunca** como imagen, ya que no se puede reproducir. Edita tu pregunta y copia bien tu código para que otros puedan reproducirlo y ayudarte con tu problema. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Claro, olvidé ese detalle, ya lo acabo de modificar, muchas gracias

Comment: a mí tu código me funciona perfectamente. Debe haber otra cosa interfiriendo. Tienes que depurarlo paso por paso en modo Debug. Ejecuta tu código con F8 y ejecuta línea a línea para que veas el momento exacto en el que el código falla.

Comment: Wow, ¿cuantos productos ingresaste?, a mí me falla desde el segundo producto, pero tendré muy en cuenta tu respuesta, se me hace raro que a tí te funcione bien y a mí no, gracias por tu aporte.